# I want to create a category price rule in Magento 2 but the rules is not applied correctly to products with special price

Tags: php, magento2

example product: with a price of 8.50 and a discount of 0.50 -> Final price 8.00
after the catalog rule (10%) it is supposed to go at 7.20 but it's 7.65.
I need a discount for a special price and not at the original price.

I found this code under /vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Model/Rule.php

```
public function calcProductPriceRule(Product $product, $price)
    {
        $priceRules = null;
        $productId = $product->getId();
        $storeId = $product->getStoreId();
        $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getWebsiteId();
        if ($product->hasCustomerGroupId()) {
            $customerGroupId = $product->getCustomerGroupId();
        } else {
            $customerGroupId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
        }
        $dateTs = $this->_localeDate->scopeTimeStamp($storeId);
        $cacheKey = date('Y-m-d', $dateTs) . "|{$websiteId}|{$customerGroupId}|{$productId}|{$price}";

        if (!array_key_exists($cacheKey, self::$_priceRulesData)) {
            $rulesData = $this->_getRulesFromProduct($dateTs, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $productId);
            if ($rulesData) {
                foreach ($rulesData as $ruleData) {
                    if ($product->getParentId()) {
                        $priceRules = $priceRules ? $priceRules : $price;
                        if ($ruleData['action_stop']) {
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $priceRules = $this->_catalogRuleData->calcPriceRule(
                            $ruleData['action_operator'],
                            $ruleData['action_amount'],
                            $priceRules ? $priceRules : $price
                        );
                        if ($ruleData['action_stop']) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return self::$_priceRulesData[$cacheKey] = $priceRules;
            } else {
                self::$_priceRulesData[$cacheKey] = null;
            }
        } else {
            return self::$_priceRulesData[$cacheKey];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

do you not have the `Adjust final price to this percentage` Action under the cart price rules? I think this option is referred to as `by_percent` in the code. Which magento calculates as

```
            case 'by_percent':
            $priceRule = $price * (1 - $ruleAmount / 100);
            break;
```